# Request sql for computed column (age)

Tags: sql, heidisql, laragon

I have trouble with my computed column for calculate automatically age.
I use latest version of Laragon, with HeidiSQL (11.2.06213).

See the request :

```
    CREATE TABLE client(
        id_client             Int  Auto_increment  NOT NULL ,
        
        client_date_naissance Date NOT NULL ,
       
        age    Int AS YEAR(NOW) - YEAR(client_date_naissance) 
    - (CASE WHEN MONTH(client_date_naissance) > MONTH(NOW) 
OR (MONTH(@client_date_naissance) = MONTH(NOW) 
AND DAY(client_date_naissance) > DAY(NOW)) THEN 1 ELSE END);
    
    ,CONSTRAINT client_PK PRIMARY KEY (id_client)
    )ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I tried with "`currendate`" instead of "`NOW`", same with supressed the "int" for age.

In SQL's doc, i found this "`TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,birth,CURDATE())` " but doesn't work.

I precise , the meaning of "client_date_naissance" (french) is  equal to birthday.

The error, for all case is :

> Erreur SQL (1064) : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near 'YEAR(NOW) - YEAR(client_date_naissance) - (CASE
> WHEN MONTH(client_date_naissance'

Any ideas ?
Thank for support.

Comment: Debugging tip: try a simpler condition in your CASE/WHEN and build up to what you have. You may need additional parentheses. Also, shouldn't the ELSE return an actual value since you're subtracting it from something?

Comment: http://www.noelshack.com/2022-30-4-1659027453-jer.png

Same with a simple request.

Comment: DATEDIFF only takes two arguments. As https://www.heidisql.com/forum.php?t=536 notes, you have to divide to get some other unit.

Comment: Arf, same in php my admin...  Is it possible what i want to do  unless ? I found the concept of computed column attractive...

Comment: Does HeidiSQL support VIEWs? That's where you'd get computed columns

Comment: I don't think so...  I didn't see VIEWS on their forum...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246885/discussion-between-barry-carter-and-jeremy).